# How to properly import dictionary in python and how to modify imported dictionary

Tags: python

I have a file called other.py

```
from src.data import users_stats
from datetime import timezone, datetime
first_timestamp = round(datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp())

def clear_v1():
    users_stats.clear()
    users_stats = {'channels_exist': [{'num_channels_exist': 0, 'time_stamp': first_timestamp}],
                'dms_exist': [{'num_dms_exist': 0, 'time_stamp': first_timestamp}],
                'messages_exist': [{'num_messages_exist': 0, 'time_stamp': first_timestamp}]}
```

another file called data.py

```
from datetime import timezone, datetime
first_timestamp = round(datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp())
users_stats = {'channels_exist': [{'num_channels_exist': 0, 'time_stamp': first_timestamp}],
                'dms_exist': [{'num_dms_exist': 0, 'time_stamp': first_timestamp}],
                'messages_exist': [{'num_messages_exist': 0, 'time_stamp': first_timestamp}]}
```

I want to Initialise the dictionary(users_stats) with the data(like in data.py). And when clear_v1 is called i want the dictionary(now filled with other data as well) to go back to the initial state.

Whenever i call clear, it says reference before assignment, which i think the programs think that i called users_stats.clear() before assignment. But isn't the users_stats imported from data.py so it is assigned already?

I have tried deleting the line users_stats.clear() and adding global user_stats, but the dictionary doesn't go back to the initial state.

Question: how do you make the users_stats in data.py back to the initial state in clear_v1()?

Edit: Sorry didn't provide more details for the problem.
my folder structure is like:

```
project-backend
 ┣ src
 ┃ ┣ data.py
 ┃ ┗ other.py
 ┗ tests
 ┃ ┗ testing.py
```

the testing file looks like:

```
from src.data import users_stats
from src.other import clear_v1()

print(users_stats)
users_stats['messages_exist'][0] = 'changed'
print(users_stats)
clear_v1()
print(users_stats)
```

def clear_v1() looks like:

```
def clear_v1():
    users_stats = {'channels_exist': [{'num_channels_exist': 0,'time_stamp': first_timestamp}],
    'dms_exist': [{'num_dms_exist': 0, 'time_stamp': first_timestamp}],
    'messages_exist': [{'num_messages_exist': 0, 'time_stamp': first_timestamp}]}
```

and it prints

```
{'channels_exist': [{'num_channels_exist': 0, 'time_stamp': 1618783441}], 'dms_exist': [{'num_dms_exist': 0, 'time_stamp': 1618783441}], 'messages_exist': [{'num_messages_exist': 0, 'time_stamp': 1618783441}]}
{'channels_exist': [{'num_channels_exist': 0, 'time_stamp': 1618783441}], 'dms_exist': [{'num_dms_exist': 0, 'time_stamp': 1618783441}], 'messages_exist': ['changed']}
{'channels_exist': [{'num_channels_exist': 0, 'time_stamp': 1618783441}], 'dms_exist': [{'num_dms_exist': 0, 'time_stamp': 1618783441}], 'messages_exist': ['changed']}
```

Edit2: I solved it by trying similar thing to the answer like

```
def clear_v1():
    first_timestamp = round(datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp())
    og_users_stats = {'channels_exist': [{'num_channels_exist': 0, 'time_stamp': first_timestamp}],
              'dms_exist': [{'num_dms_exist': 0, 'time_stamp': first_timestamp}],
              'messages_exist': [{'num_messages_exist': 0, 'time_stamp': first_timestamp}]}   
    users_stats.clear()
    users_stats.update(og_users_stats)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what your issue is as far as "reference before assignment". It would have been helpful if you had provided a stacktrace. My directory structure is:

```
lib
   src
      data.py
```

I then set environment variable `PYTHONPATH` to point to directory **lib**. My file **other.py** is (or you can place **other.py** in directory **lib**):

```py
from src.data import users_stats
from copy import deepcopy

save_users_stats = deepcopy(users_stats)

def clear_v1():
    users_stats.clear()
    users_stats.update(save_users_stats)

# change users_stats:
users_stats['messages_exist'][0] = 'changed'
# copy the reference:
d = users_stats
print(d)
clear_v1()
print(d)
```

Prints:

```
{'channels_exist': [{'num_channels_exist': 0, 'time_stamp': 1618730138}], 'dms_exist': [{'num_dms_exist': 0, 'time_stamp': 1618730138}], 'messages_exist': ['changed']}
{'channels_exist': [{'num_channels_exist': 0, 'time_stamp': 1618730138}], 'dms_exist': [{'num_dms_exist': 0, 'time_stamp': 1618730138}], 'messages_exist': [{'num_messages_exist': 0, 'time_stamp': 1618730138}]}
```

After importing `user_stats`, **other.py** uses `deepcopy` to makes a deep copy of the dictionary as `save_user_stats`. Then `clear_v1` clears and updates in place the current `user_stats` dictionary rather than assigning a new dictionary reference to `user_stats` in case there is a copy of the `user_stats` reference being used in which case that reference copy would still be pointing to the modified dictionary. As you can see, I have no problems referencing `users_stats` from function `clear_v1`.

**Note**

Your code clears the `users_stats` dictionary but then reassigns a completely new dictionary to `users_stats` making the clear operation you performed totally superfluous. Moreover, in my sample code where I have made a copy of the reference to the `users_stats` dictionary, `d`, after calling your `clear_v1`, my `d` would now be pointing to an empty dictionary. With my implementation of `clear_v1` it is still pointing to the original `clear_stats` dictionary that has been simply updated with the original values. By the way, ending up with a copy of the reference to the dictionary is entirely possible. You could easily have a class that gets instantiated with this dictionary as follows:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, users_stats):
        self._users_stats = users_stats # this is a copy of the reference

    ... #etc
```